# Creating a live search bar with Ajax & PHP and pass result to PHP variable or plain text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a form where you can add orders with different details to the database. In this form there is a field called `Client` where you can create a new client or select an existing one.

To make this last part I found some snippets of a live bar with Ajax. It works fine and you get the results, but I want the selected result to be passed to a PHP variable to update the client field in the database.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Search bar</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search client..." />
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
    <p> Selected result: </p>


</body>
</html>
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_REQUEST["term"])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre LIKE ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);

        $param_term = $_REQUEST["term"] . '%';

        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    echo "<p>" . $row["nombre"] . " | (ID:" . $row["id"] . ")</p>";
                }
            } else{
                echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Here are a few pics if it helps to see what I mean:

[Search bar after typing something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Chl.png)

[Search bar after selecting one of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZmCG.png)

Comment: You mean `echo "<p><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"saveToPhp('" . $row["nombre"] . " | (ID:" . $row["id"] . "')\"></button>" . $row["nombre"] . " | (ID:" . $row["id"] . "</p>";` and then hook up another ajax?

Comment: Actually what I want is to pass this part: ```$(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text()); ``` (Which is the moment you click and select one of the few results you get) to a variable and then pass it to a php variable or to plain text, so I can put it in a form value and when I submit it it passes through mysql to the database and updates the client.

Comment: I updated the post with photos to help explain what I mean.

Comment: Feel free to delete your answer and question. It is very specific to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if I get it right, you should not pass it to a variable on php. You need to use ajax once more but instead of getting something from the database using get, you should add/update somthing to the database using post.
$.post(...)
And then you need to control the route you set in your ajax and voilà.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I updated the post with photos to help explain what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it placing the code inside the form, thanks for your time!